# How to include user type column in data dictionary - Visual Paradigm

Tags: data-dictionary, visual-paradigm, er-diagram

Designed a data model with ER diagram. Defined Both user type and data type for all columns. But when i try to generate report and produce data dictionary , user type column is not included. 
So is it possible to include User type column in the data dictionary produced ?